# Magnitude calculation in python

Tags: python, flux

i'm trying to calculate magnitudes of some stars based on their flux but I keep getting the wrong values and I don't know why.
For example:

The first star has a flux in the V-band of 39,984. Its V-magnitude is equal to 10.1 - 2.5log(39,984/1,220,000) =  13,8 (the 10.1 and 1,220,000 are from a reference star). But my program calculates a magnitude of 18.65. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import asciidata

fv = [] 
fb = []
data = asciidata.open('Flux.txt')
for i in data[1]:
    fv.append(float(i))
for i in data[2]:
    fb.append(float(i))

mv = []
mb = []
mbv = []
for i in range (0,25):
    mv.append(10.1 - 2.5 * np.log(fv[i]/1220000))
    mb.append(11.0 - 2.5 * np.log(fb[i]/339368))
    print i+1, mv[i], mb[i]
```

Comment: you should have a look at numpy.vectorize: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html, it will spare some unnecessary loops

Comment: @bendaizer -- It looks like OP only has 25 stars ... I'm not sure if vectorizing it is worth the additional complexity :).  Of course, other improvements could be made with list-comprehensions and possibly `zip` ...

Comment: @mgilson I wasn't refering to this specific case but merely pointing to the existence of the vectorize function, which comes in very handy when arrays start to get really big :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to use `numpy.log10` (log base 10) instead of `numpy.log` (base 2).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 10.1 - 2.5*np.log(39984./1220000)
18.645316909086766
>>> 10.1 - 2.5*np.log10(39984./1220000)
13.811183979730934
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the right log function:

```
In [467]: 10.1 - 2.5 * np.log(39984/1220000)
Out[467]: 18.645316909086766

In [468]: 10.1 - 2.5 * np.log10(39984/1220000)
Out[468]: 13.811183979730934
```

**Note**: Python 3